# OnClickListener for TextView does not get called

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener, spanned, linkmovementmethod

I have a couple of **text links** in my Android applications which are either **email addresses** or **web links**. I use the following code snippet to set them up (example for a web link):

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(textViewId);
spannedText = Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + url + "\">" + titleText + "</a>");
textView.setText(spannedText, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Handle click
    }
});
```

The `TextView` has **no** special attributes set such as `android:linksClickable`, `android:clickable` or `android:focusable`. Its style inherits from `@android:style/TextAppearance.Small`.

For some reason the `OnClickListener` never gets called.

Comment: you need to use that one thing. `LinkMovementMethod` or `OnClick`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove this code

```
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

and manually add the following a link

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Handle click
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

Comment: Thx. Although it is really strange that the `OnClickListener` does not overwrite the settings of `LinkMovementMethod`. Still I do not understand what `LinkMovementMethod` actually is good for. Please note that you have to prefix the `url` string with `"mailto:"` in case of email links.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to tell from the snippet of code you have pasted. Please show more code. For instance, what does your declaration of textView look like?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an onClick listener on a parent view that might be overriding the text view? Also youmight want to try not using an anonymous inner class as your listener an instead use the view.OnClickListener below for click events.

```
myActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    publiv void onClick(View v) {
        if(V.getId() == textViewId) {
             // do work
        }
    }
}
```